# How to take bytes from web address, and then convert to .png

Tags: python, hex, png

I am struggling to take the data from this  [page](https://pxls.space/boarddata)

What I want to do is take the raw data from the page, and convert it into an image (.png).
The page data is storing hex codes.
I am not sure what imports to use.
I also could use a few lines of code to get me started.

Comment: It seems that it is not a `png` file.

Comment: I want to convert the hex codes into a png

Comment: Did you only want to get the bytes of the file?

Comment: I want for my finished result to have a png

Comment: Are you sure it is a image?How do you convert it?Will you use some methods to decrypt it?I save the bytes of file and convert it to png.Surely,this is not a image file.It can not be opened normally.